# Implement MS Word functionality in C#

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, ms-word, office-interop

I am trying to reference MS Word in my C# program using the Microsoft.Office.Interop namespace. In Word, we can insert images in a document and use the "Remove Background" feature to specify a portion of the image and remove other parts. Is there a way to do this with the Interop namespace?? Or am I supposed to resort to manual methods??

Comment: What have you tried so far? It might be worth looking on MSDN for documentation about the office interop for some tips and methods you could use.

Comment: Office Open Xml SDK is a sounder choice

Comment: @WaiHaLee I am trying to find a way using Interop.Word but in the MSDN documentation, I was able to find only functions about using the Word functionality specific to text. Nothing about working on the image as far as i understood.

Comment: @andrei.ciprian Thanks.. I'll look into it and let you know..

Answer (score 0):

Word allows to record a VBA macro in the background. Thus, you will find what properties and methods can be used to get the job done. Note, the Word object model is common for all kind of applications. See [Create or run a macro](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Create-or-run-a-macro-c6b99036-905c-49a6-818a-dfb98b7c3c9c) for more information.

Open XML SDK is another alternative way to get the job done. But in some cases it is easier to automate Word than deal with XML. See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Where do you run the code? A web server? ASP.NET?

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I'm trying to use the functionality in a C# Windows application..

Comment: Okay. You are free to automate Office applications in that case.

Comment: Are there scenarios where this wouldn't be feasible?? Let's say I want to implement the same in a JSP or ASP.Net or Android app... Would I face challenges?? *Just clarifying*

Comment: Let me clarify my purpose here.. I'm trying to bring the "Remove Background" functionality for an image captured in my C# app.. I don't need to create a Word doc but I need to implement the functionality.. Is that a good approach from my side?

Comment: Yep. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0).